# How do I remove a sub resource by restful PATCH

Tags: rest, patch, restful-architecture, http-verbs

When we use PATCH, we are partially updating a resource. What's the best practice if I want to remove part of the resource?

For example: we have a Person resource:

```
Person:
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'test',
  companyId: 1,
}
```

Lets say this person leaves the company and has no job, then the companyId should be set as `null` in the DB. When I want to remove the `companyId` in `Person` via API, shall I set the companyId in the payload as `null` as well?

`PATCH: /person/3`

```
Person:
{
  id: 3,
  companyId: null,
}
```

I used to remove an object by setting it as `{}`, or remove an array by setting it as `[]`, but I am not 100% sure what's the best practice for a primitive property (like the `companyId` in this case). Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.2) (which defines the Patch standard), from the client's perspective the API could be called like

```
PATCH /person/3

[
    { "op": "remove", "path": "/companyId"}
]
```

I think the exact internal implementation (nullable int vs 0/-1 as default) is up to you.

Comment: *Proposed* standard. Not accepted yet, though I personally think it's the right approach to `PATCH`.